# Change package name of my react native app in google play store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have uploaded my react native app to internal test mode on the google play store. I noticed that my package name is appearing misspelled on the play store. Is there a way I can change that? I have tried uploading the new build but it's not accepting. If I cannot change that then what is the alternative solution I can use?

Comment: Do you want to change `PackageName` in your project?

Answer (score 1):

I had a issue related to changing name of my project name and also package name, I used this packge, I installed it and fellow the steps. So, after all things running well and package name was changed, I removed this package.
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload an app to the Play Store, you can not change the signing key nor the application ID (package name).
(You can swap the signig key if you still have access to the original one).

Your only option is to create a new Play Store app.